# Razor Pages .NET Core 2.1 Child Routes

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I'm working on a .NET Core 2.1 Razor Pages application, and can't figure out why the router isn't matching my expectations.  In my application an Orchestration object has a collection of Rules objects.  An Orchestration is defined queried at the DB with a Guid.

My Index.cshtml in the Orchestration folder looks like

```
@page "{id:guid}"
@model Website.Pages.Orchestration.OrchestrationModel
```

and predictably `localhost/Orchestration/{guid}` routes to the correct page.

My goal is `localhost/Orchestration/{guid}/rule/{ruleId}/edit` to hit the Edit.cshtml in the Rule folder.  My attempts are close, but .NET is matching `Orchestration/rule` instead of `Orchestration/{guid}/rule`.  I've tried several incantations trying to add `{orchestrationid}/{id}` to my Edit.cshtml in the Rule directory, but it's not working.  This seems possible, I appreciate any help on what I'm missing.

*note rule/Index.cshtml has been renamed to Edit*

The Edit.cshtml file looks like

```
@page "{id}"
@model Website.Pages.Orchestration.Rule.RuleModel
```

The part that doesn't working is trying to access the child routes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is to override the default routing system that relies on matching URLs to file paths. You can do this by specifying an [override route template](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes) as part of the `@page` directive. Override route templates are prefixed with an option tilde (`~`) and a forward slash, so the following should work for you:

```
@page "/Orchestration/{id:guid}/rule/{ruleId:int}/edit"
```